# ContentDispositionHeaderValue.FileName vs IFormFile.FileName in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

All the code on the internet regarding the upload of file is using `ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName`

But I see that `IFormFile` also has a `FileName`.

What is the difference between them and why use the first solution instead of the second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IFormFile` was introduced only in  .NET Core 2. It's more convenient to work with `IFormFile` when you use .NET Core 2 or higher. But if you work with the previous version of Asp.net you don't have much choice except of `ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName`

Comment: Do you know if there is an official documentation that states that IFormFile.FileName will return the same value as the ContentDispositionHeaderValue.FileName?

Comment: @Dan, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.name?view=aspnetcore-2.1
it says "Gets the form field name from the Content-Disposition header."

Comment: I already saw that but it does not guaranty that it will return the same thing.  Anyway thank you for the clarification.